# Generators for a subgroup of a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F$ be a finitely generated free group and $G$  a finite group and $\phi :F\to G$ some homomorphism. Is there a method to calculate generators for the kernel of $\phi$. Note I'm looking for actual generators not a presentation. If you can add a reference it would be even better.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to computing a presentation of $G$? If you have $G = <F | R>$, where $R$ are the relations (e.g. something like $a^5b^4$ might be an element of $R$), then $R$ should be exactly the generators of the kernel. Hence, any method to compute a presentation of $G$ should solve your problem.

Comment: No for instance take a homomorphism from a free group on x,y to $\mathbb{Z}$  taking x to 1 and y to 0 then the relation y=1 is enough for a presentation but  it doesn't generate the kernel because $x^{-1}yx$ is in the kernel but not generated by y.

Comment: relations are generators of the minimal normal subgroup containing them and I'm looking for generators s.t. the kernel is the minimal subgroup containing them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do this is to look into the proof of the Nielsen-Schreier theorem. Let $X$ be the set of free generators of $F$, and let $U$ be a *Schreier transversal* for $\ker \phi$. Then construct the set $A = \{ u x \overline{u x}^{-1} \mid u \in U, x \in X^{\pm 1} \}$. It turns out that the set $A$ generates $\ker \phi$. This generating set can be reduced to a minimal one if you require that $ux \notin U$. The obtained subset of $A$ freely generates $\ker \phi$. For all the details, see the book D. L. Johnson: *Presentations of Groups*, Chapter 2.